# Error: impossible to find or load main class when running jar file on windows

Tags: java, gradle, jar

I am working on a java project using gradle for a homework assignment and I got troubles running JAR files built off gradle via the windows command prompt : 
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DRSgT.jpg)

Here's my build.gradle txt :

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'antlr'

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
  antlr 'org.antlr:antlr4:4.7.1'
  testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

generateGrammarSource {
  arguments += ['-no-visitor', '-no-listener']
  outputDirectory = new File(buildDir.toString() + "/generated-src/antlr/main/TP2/")
}

jar {
  manifest {
    attributes (
      'Main-Class': 'TP2.Main',
      'Class-Path': configurations.runtimeClasspath.files.join(' ')
    )
  }
}
```

I've already checked my classpath directory, class name... When I type the next command : `jar -tf build\libs\TP2.jar` I can see my class well packed in my jar and my class is at this directory : build\classes\java\main\TP2\Main.class 
So I don't see why it is not working. 
I'm not an expert with gradle that's why any help would be really appreciated but I think the problem propably come from the manifest.

Comment: Your class file should be in the location `TP2\Main.class`.

Comment: It is specified in the classpath where to find the class file, I tried in case and this is not working so the problem is somewhere else

Comment: That's not how the Classpath attribute works. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html